# Access control at process level

Tags: linux, process, access-control

I'm sorry if this was asked but I was unable to find a satisfcatory answer. I know how access control works with respect to objects (files, devices, etc.), but it's not clear to me how this translate to processes.

Let's say that user U1 starts a process P1, then P1 will be marked with UID(U1) and GID(U1). Now, if P2 is a process started by another user U2, what can P2 do to P1? Can it kill it? Can it see its address space (like a debugger etc.)? How is this decided with respect to UID(U1), GID(U1), UID(U2) and GID(U2)?

Comment: As for kill , see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html Notice that you need to be able to see target process at least, like you're in the same pid namespace or you hold a pidfd of the target then you can use  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_send_signal.2.html   Debugging needs ptrace, which is much more complex, not just related to UID of process. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html

Comment: processes are not file, they can't be read/write like files, although we have pid fd now, which can be poll(), but pidfd still doesn't have access token